# Is it necessary to make a rollback on a transaction in the catch-block?

Tags: java, transactions, eclipselink

Maybe a stupid question, but is it necessary to make a rollback on a transaction in the catch-block if the EntityManager.merge() throws an exception?
Or does the exception itself mean that the merge won´t work so that next time I run commit the previous changes that throwed the exception won´t apply?

Example:

```
public void setPerson(Person person) {
EntityManagerFactory emf =   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyLib");
     EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
     try {            
         if(!em.getTransaction().isActive()){
            em.getTransaction().begin();
         }
         em.merge(person);
         em.getTransaction().commit();
         emf.getCache().evict(Person.class); // clear Person cache
     } catch (Exception ex){
         em.getTransaction().rollback(); // Is this necessary?   
     } finally {
         em.close();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on the details of `em.merge(person)` method and the implementation of your database driver.

If that method only performs one update statement, then the `rollback` is superfluous.  If however it may run multiple updates, then it's not that clear.

I personally would keep it there

If the `rollback` is removed and your `merge` method errors our after some updates are done but others are not, then closing a database connection without explicit `commit` or `rollback` will either commit or rollback the transaction, depending on the driver implementation.  According to the [javadoc for `java.sql.Connection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29), the behaviour depends on the implementation.  Hence you may end up committing partial updates if you do not `rollback` yourself on error.

Comment: But then you could say that it doesn´t hurt to have the rollback in the catch block? Am I right?

Comment: @Rox Not only does it not hurt, it may be necessary if you want to avoid some undesired effects.